# How add extra attribute in model object response in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I have a method to render user details after login. The method is as follows

```
def respond_with(resource, _opts = {})        
        render json:resource
```

I get the User object in the resource variable. I want to add a new attribute called token before rendering it. I tried `resource.attributes.merge(new:"value")` but its not working.

Answer (score 3):

I think following will work 
`render json: resource.as_json.merge(new: 'value')`

If you want to have new attribute for your model, you can define a `attr_accessor` inside that model Class